# How to access $scope variable declared in service callback function in ng-init or ng-checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have service.js in which authentication takes place.On success service callback function is executed from controller.js

service.js:

```
 'use strict';
 angular.module('Authentication')
.factory('AuthenticationService', ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope','$timeout', '$location', '$window',
function ($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, $window) {
        var service = {};


        service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

            $http.post('..json', {
                    headers: {
                        username: username,
                        password: password
                    }
                })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        callback(status);

                    }, 1000);
                });
        };
        return service;
}])
```

controller.js:

```
 'use strict';
angular.module('Authentication').controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', '$http', '$timeout', '$window',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService, $http, $timeout, $window) {

**$scope.name=true;**  
        $scope.login = function () {
            AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function (response) {
                if (response === 'Success') {
                    $http.get('..json').success(data,status,headers,config){
                   **$scope.value=true;**
                  })

                } else {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        };
}]);
```

HTML :

I have 2 checkboxes linked with two $scope variable from controller-$scope.name and $scope.value

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="name"> abc
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="value">xyz
```

Now since both $scope variable is set to true both checkboxes should be initially checked....but the checkbox with $scope.name is checked and $scope.value is unchecked

Any idea about why this happens and how can I make the second check box also initially checked based on the $scope.value

Comment: you said "both $scope variable is set to true" , but the way I see it, $scope.value is only true is the login succeeded, right?

Comment: Yes..thats right, so after login the checkbox should be checked right?, but is unchecked after login..These checkboxes are in html file which shows up after login

Comment: maybe the login just doesn't passes.
if you want them to be initially checked both, move the "$scope.value=true" right after $scope.name=true

Comment: Actually login is successful and in $scope.value I need a value that I get from $http response so cant move out, I wl get the value true/false after login, actual code::      **$scope.value=response.visible**

Comment: Off topic but still Id consider still useful. When this gets bigger with more features etc you will find it far easier to manage and scale if you work with promises instead of callbacks. You already have a nested `$http` call in your exmaple. With promises you can flatten it out and chain your promises rarely needing to nest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/319rp1Lh/2/) is a working version almost exactly same as your original code, the only thing i see might be wrong is `if (response === 'Success')`, because in my example code, the `status` in `.success(data,status,headers,config)` is a number not string like "Success", also check this official document [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: `if(response=== 'success' )` does work as other stuff inside it does execute, just this $scope variabale is not accessible in ng-init or ng-checked

Comment: have your tried to console log $scope.value after it got assigned? does it return the correct value in console?

Comment: Yes it returns correct value in console...it works fine in js...even an alert shows the correct value

Comment: then try this, change `$scope.value=true;` to `$scope.$apply(function () {$scope.value=true;});`

Comment: it might be when you change the the value in `$scope`, somehow it did not trigger the digest cycle

Comment: Yes, that worked with ng-checked, just for information can u tell me why this isn't working : `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="val" ng-init="val=value" />xyz`   This should also show the checkbox checked initially

Comment: ng-init only trigger once when angularjs process the html template first time, it assign the value of `value` which is undefined at the beginning to `val`, it does not bind `val` with `value`, if you want to do the bi-direction binding you should do this `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value" />xyz`

Comment: if you use ng-init, you have to force angular to refresh the page(for example, $route.reload()) to reload the controller for getting the new value

Comment: if it's helpful, please accept my solution :) Thanks